# Go type conversions and unexported CGo types

Tags: types, type-conversion, go

Suppose there is CGo package with a struct defined like this:

```
package test
...
type Test struct {
    Field *C.C_Test
}
...
```

Now suppose that from somewhere else I get `unsafe.Pointer` which I know points to `C_Test` C structure.

Do I understand correctly that there is *completely* no way to create new `test.Test` instance from the `unsafe.Pointer` value while being in a package *other* than `test`?

Attempting to use something like `&test.Test{ptr}`, where `ptr` is `unsafe.Pointer` value, fails for obvious reasons with message `cannot use ptr (type unsafe.Pointer) as type *test._Ctype_C_Test` in field value, and type conversion to `*test._Ctype_C_Test` does not work as well because this type is not exported.
And I think that making my other module to use CGo and redefining the same C structure in it will not work either since that package will have something like `client._Ctype_C_Test` but `test.Test` requires `test._Ctype_C_Test`, and they are different from the point of view of the typechecker.

**Some background:** I need a way to create such structure when I use `GtkBuilder` with [`go-gtk`](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk) library.
Its `GtkBuilder.GetObject(name)` method returns `*GObject` pointer which in turn contains `unsafe.Pointer` field which I need to turn somehow into, say, `gtk.GtkEntry` struct. `gtk.GtkEntry` itself contains implicit field of type `gtk.GtkWidget` which has explicit field of type `*C.GtkWidget`, so I need to convert `unsafe.Pointer` to `*C.GtkWidget`, but I cannot, as I have described in the simple example above.

**Update:** here is the code I'm trying to force to work: https://gist.github.com/4141343

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked a [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/PsbWJeWD0VQ) on golang-nuts and was given an example on how to do what I want. It seems to work now. Here is the code from Ian's answer:

```
var t test.Test
p := (*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&t.Field))
*p = unsafe.Pointer(u)
```

So, all what was needed is double cast to `unsafe.Pointer` and then to `*unsafe.Pointer`. I came up with the following code to simplify the assign process:

```
func Assign(to unsafe.Pointer, from unsafe.Pointer) {
    fptr := (*unsafe.Pointer)(from)
    tptr := (*unsafe.Pointer)(to)
    *tptr = *fptr
}

func Init(builder *gtk.GtkBuilder) {
    messageNameEntryWidget := gtk.GtkWidget{}
    Assign(unsafe.Pointer(&messageNameEntryWidget.Widget),
           unsafe.Pointer(&builder.GetObject("messageNameEntry").Object))
}
```

Then, however, I decided to abstain from using GTK, since it is painful to do tricks like this) but this is not related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Was something like

```
foo := test.Test{}
*(unsafe.Pointer)(&foo.Field) = ptr
```

also tested? I would expect that to work. (Hope so. Kinda.)

EDIT 2012-11-24 13:42 UTC: 2nd attempt

```
package main

/*

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
        int foo;
        char *bar;
} Test_t;

void test_dump(Test_t *test) {
        printf(".foo %d, .bar %s\n", test->foo, test->bar);
}

void *test_new(int foo, char *bar) {
        Test_t *p = malloc(sizeof(Test_t));
        p->foo = foo;
        p->bar = bar;
        return p;
}

*/
import "C"

import "unsafe"

type Test struct {
        Field *C.Test_t
}

func main() {
        hello := C.CString("Hello")
        defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(hello))
        test := &Test{(*C.Test_t)(C.test_new(42, hello))}
        C.test_dump(test.Field)
}
```

---

```
$ go clean && go build && ls
main.go  13535422
$ ./13535422 
.foo 42, .bar Hello
$
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, this does not work. I'm getting `invalid indirect of unsafe.Pointer(&foo.Field) (type unsafe.Pointer)` in terms of example.

Comment: Yes, your code will work, because C structure definition is in the same package as the unsafe pointer conversion attempt. I wrote about this in my answer. Try moving `main` function in separate package and you will see what I mean. I will add example code shortly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'question' instead of 'answer' :)